# How to properly remove a bazaar branch?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

How to properly remove a bazaar branch from a repository?

What if I want to remove a branch completely, so it would be impossible to find if this branch existed?

I'm aware of the `remove-branch` command, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

`bzr remove-branch` is the easiest way to remove a branch. If you can't use that command, can you mention why not?

You can also just remove the branch directory manually, e.g.: `bzr rm -rf .bzr/branch`. This will however skip several checks that `bzr remove-branch` will do.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ditch the branch, you can just use plain `rm -rf branch_name` (or similar machinery on Windows, including cleaning Recycle Bin).

Some history still be preserved in shared repository though, and could be found with `bzr heads --dead` command. If you absolutely need to be sure no hidden history left you need to do something more involved:

```
# make new empty shared repository
bzr init-repo /path/to/temp-repo
# branch everything from old repo to temp-repo
bzr branch /path/to/old-repo/branch-1 /path/to/temp-repo/branch-1
...
bzr branch /path/to/old-repo/branch-N /path/to/temp-repo/branch-N
# after that you're ready to delete old-repo and replace it with temp-repo
# newly created repo will have only revisions present in active branches
```